# Crystal Report Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

I have made a crystal report in asp.net for web application. Some report open nicely. But sometimes it does not. It shows the following problem.

> Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))
>   Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Stack Trace: 
>   [COMException (0x8002000b): Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))]
>      Report_Viewer.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +894
>      System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927

My VS: VS 2008, Database:MS SQL Express 2005, OS:Windows 7

Is there any one to solve my problem..

NB: My code is in a Class

```
public ReportDocument ShowReport(string ReportName, string Parameter1)
{                              
    try
    {
        cryRpt.Load(ReportName);            
        cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon(UserName, Password, ServerName, DatabaseName);                                    
        crParameterValues.Clear();
        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = Parameter1;// as like Parameter1
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
        crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["@Parameter1"];
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;
        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw ex;
       //ShowReport(@"default_report.rpt");
    }
    //CleareParameter();
    return cryRpt;
}
```

Report Viewer Page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ReportName="";
    string Parameter1="";
    ReportName= Session["ReportName "].ToString();
    Parameter1 = Session["Parameter1"].ToString();
    }
    try
    {
        if (Session["Parameter2"].ToString() != null)
        {
            Parameter2 = Session["Parameter2"].ToString();
            icount = icount + 1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ) { }
    ReportViewer oReportViewer = new ReportViewer(); // Class file
    ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
    try
    {
        rptDoc = oReportViewer.ShowReport(ReportName, Parameter1);
        rptDoc = oReportViewer.ShowReport(ReportName, Parameter1, 
        rptDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "Report");
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {  
       throw ex;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

crParameterFieldDefinitions["@Parameter1"];

Above line you will check that parameter exist or not. I think that one is not available.

Hope this one is helpful!!!

Answer (score 23):

That is because the parameters (or parameters names) you set in your code are different from defined parameters in your report

Answer (score 2):

1. Add One Method

```
Public Sub LoadReport()
    Try
        If Validation() = True Then Exit Sub

        If ClsDcon.ShowItems(Me.Text) = False Then Exit Sub
        Dim lvarr(4, 1) As String

        lvarr(0, 0) = "@CompId"
        lvarr(0, 1) = Connection.strGCompanyId  'strCompId

        lvarr(1, 0) = "@DepartmentId"
        lvarr(1, 1) = txtstaffAbscentees.GetTextBox.Tag      'strSDMUId

        lvarr(2, 0) = "@FromDate"
        lvarr(2, 1) = ClsDcon.ConvertDateToInt(dtpFromDate.GetTextBox.Text)                  'strFromDate

        lvarr(3, 0) = "@PFromDate"
        lvarr(3, 1) = "Staff Abscentees Report On: " & dtpFromDate.GetTextBox.Text 'ClsDcon.ConvertIntToDate(strFromDate)

        lvarr(4, 0) = "@Flags"
        lvarr(4, 1) = intFlag

        Me.Text = frmMain
        ClsDcon.LoadCrystalReport(New CrtStaffAbscentees, crpStaffAbscenteesReportviewer, lvarr)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

****2. Add Function To Load and Set Parameter****

```
Public Sub LoadCrystalReport(ByVal pvcrpReport As Object, ByVal pvcrvControl As CrystalReportViewer, Optional ByVal pvarrParamValues As Array = Nothing, Optional ByVal pvstrSelection As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal invVal As Integer = 0)
    Try

        Dim lvobjReport As Object = pvcrpReport
        'myRpt.Load("D:\Projects\MyAccountswin2008new\UILayer\Sales\Sales Reports\CrtPOSBillReport.rpt")

        For i As Integer = 0 To pvarrParamValues.GetUpperBound(0)
            lvobjReport.SetParameterValue(pvarrParamValues(i, 0).ToString, pvarrParamValues(i, 1))
        Next

        Dim lsMethod As String = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
        Dim loConnInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo
        'Dim lsMode As String = Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Mode")
        loConnInfo.ServerName = My.Settings.RPTServerName
        loConnInfo.DatabaseName = My.Settings.RPTDatabaseName
        loConnInfo.UserID = My.Settings.RPTUserID
        loConnInfo.Password = My.Settings.RPTPassword
        Dim loTables As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables
        Dim loTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
        Dim loTableLogonInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
        loTables = lvobjReport.Database.Tables
        For Each loTable In loTables
            loTableLogonInfo = loTable.LogOnInfo
            loTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = loConnInfo
            loTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(loTableLogonInfo)
            loTable.Location = loTable.Name
        Next
        'pvcrvControl.RefreshReport()
        pvcrvControl.ReportSource = lvobjReport
        pvcrvControl.Refresh()
        'pvcrvControl.RefreshReport()
        If invVal = 1 Then
            Dim prd As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
            lvobjReport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = prd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
            If lvobjReport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "" Or lvobjReport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = Nothing Then
                MyMessagebox.MyMessagebox.ShowMessage("Set Default Printer", "Global Funtions_UI", MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If

            'prd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = PaperKind.Custom
            'prd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.PaperName = "NewSize"
            'Dim prnPS As New Printing.PaperSize("HalfFolio", 850, 650)
            'Dim intIdx As Integer

            'For intIdx = 0 To prd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1 Step 1
            '    If prd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(intIdx).Kind = Printing.PaperKind.Custom Then
            '        prnPS.RawKind = prd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(intIdx).RawKind
            '        prd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = prnPS
            '    End If
            'Next
            'prd.Print()




            'If prd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Kind = PaperKind.Custom Then
            '    prd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width = 827
            '    prd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height = 650
            NumberofPrints()
            lvobjReport.PrintToPrinter(dblPrintValue, False, 0, 0)
            'End If
        ElseIf invVal = 2 Then
            Dim prd As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
            lvobjReport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = prd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
            If lvobjReport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "" Or lvobjReport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = Nothing Then
                MyMessagebox.MyMessagebox.ShowMessage("Set Default Printer", "Global Funtions_UI", MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If

            NumberOfReturnPrints()
            lvobjReport.PrintToPrinter(dblReturnPrintValue, False, 0, 0)

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MYERROR.WriteLogFile("GlobalFunctions_UI", "LoadCrystalReport", ex)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This error also occurs when you change page size setting from previous one and forgot to change code to force print using the previous page's settings.

eg. A5 > A4, but with code you are still setting page size to A5.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when your parameters not matched in both reports & coding. May be your parameter name is wrong. So verify the parameters & parameter names are same in report & your coding.